# MSVC++ - Force everything to be put into a single section except for `.reloc`

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker

I've tried using Microsoft Visual C++ `#pragma section( ".text" )` and `__declspec(allocate(".text"))` on static read-only string data. But there is still a `.rdata` section in the binary. I am NOT using the standard C libraries. I am using MSVC++ as a bytecode compiler for use with code injection.

It would greatly simplify injection by having read-only data inside the ".text" section and ***not*** the ".rdata" section. How can I do that? is there a linker option to stuff everything into one single section, or merge 2 sections together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `merge sections` option in the Microsoft linker. This looks like it will work for my purposes. `/MERGE:[from=to]`

Answer (score 0):

Put all strings and other static data in stack manually.

So you don't need other sections, except .text.

```
char String[] = { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 0 };
```

And Unicode:

```
wchar_t WideString[] = { L'H', L'e', L'l', L'l', L'o', L'\0' };
```